# How to create boundary for optimization if 3rd party library not allow it to pass through?

Tags: java, optimization, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to use Apache Lib in Java. Specifically, I am using LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer. It looks like I cannot pass the boundary condition through. Is there a way to overcome this? I guess I can return a large value if boundary is reached. But what about the Jacobian matrix?

Haven't tried anything yet as I don't know how I can pass it through